# Downloaded Data does not print in order using GCDs in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to have the downloaded return message print before the message "second".  Basically, once the message has been downloaded it should print and then the "second" message.  Everytime the code runs, the second message prints and then the returnMessage because the return message takes a bit to download.  Is it possible to allow the return message to fire after it completes and then the second message  everytime the code is run?

```
    var returnMessage: String? = ""
    var downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_async(utility.GlobalUtilityQueue){
        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)

        service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket!, object: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            // Process the response

            let json = JSON(object.JSON)


            returnMessage = json["message"].string
            println("\(returnMessage)") // print first

        })

            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)


        dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, self.utility.GlobalMainQueue) { 

        println("second")//should print second
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `dispatch_group_leave` should be *inside* the `completionHandler` of `executeQuery`.

```
var returnMessage: String? = ""
let downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()
dispatch_async(utility.GlobalUtilityQueue){
    dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)

    service.executeQuery(query) { ticket, object, error in

        // Process the response

        let json = JSON(object.JSON)

        returnMessage = json["message"].string
        println("\(returnMessage)") // will print first

        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, self.utility.GlobalMainQueue) { 
        println("second")//will print second
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is not a situation where you would use dispatch group (you'd generally only do it if you were entering and leaving multiple times). Also, the outer `dispatch_async` is probably unnecessary (you're calling an asynchronous method, so there's no need to dispatch that to some background queue). But I assume this was more of an academic question, so hopefully this helps.